# How to display sender and receiver avatars in Mailboxer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailboxer

New to ruby/rails, and just implemented mailboxer messaging for my users.  I want the users profile avatar to display during messaging, but can't seem to figure it out.  Avatars display fine on the actual user profiles.

I have the avatar displaying, but at the moment it just shows the originators avatar next to all messages of both users in the conversation.

I understand that the avatar is only displaying the original senders avatar next to both users replies, because I'm using `conversation.originator` . At the moment, it's the only way I can even get the avatar to appear, so that is my starting point.

How do I get both sender, and receivers avatars to display next to their own replies/messages?

Again, I'm new to Ruby, so this may be the simplest thing, and apologies if this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find an answer.

_messages.html.erb

```
<% @receipts.each do |receipt| %>
    <% message = receipt.message %>
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-left">
        <%= image_tag conversation.originator.profile.avatar.url, class: 'user-show-avatar' %>

      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          <%= message.sender.name %> <br>
          <small><b>Subject: </b><%= message.subject %></small><br>
          <small><b>Date: </b><%=  message.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M%p") %></small>
        </h4>
        <%= message.body %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

_conversation.html.erb

```
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">

    <%= image_tag conversation.originator.profile.avatar.url, class: 'user-show-avatar' %>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">
      <%= conversation.originator.name %> <br>
      <small><b>Subject: </b><%= conversation.subject %></small><br>
      <small><b>Date: </b><%=  conversation.messages.last.created_at.strftime("%A, %b %d, %Y at %I:%M%p") %></small>
    </h4>
    <%= truncate conversation.messages.last.body, length: 145 %>
    <%= link_to "View", conversation_path(conversation)  %>
    <% if conversation.is_trashed?(current_user) %>
        <%= link_to 'Untrash', untrash_conversation_path(conversation), method: :post %>
    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Trash', trash_conversation_path(conversation), method: :post,
                    data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

end
```

conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

 def new
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
  end

   def create
    recipients = User.find_by(id: params[:recipient_id])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
    flash[:success] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user).order("created_at ASC")
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  end


   def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

   def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body, recipients:[])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
  belongs_to :plan
  acts_as_messageable

def mailboxer_name
self.name
end

def mailboxer_email(object)
self.email
end

end
```

Comment: It seems that `conversation.originator.profile` always gives the profile of the user who started the conversation. Can you show your `model.rb` file, what does the `originator` method do?

Comment: I've edited above, and added my user model.  I don't have an originator method defined anywhere, as I thought it was something that came pre-defined with the mailboxer gem..?

Comment: Can you replace **conversation.originator.profile.avatar.url** with this **message.sender.user.profile.avatar.url** and check? I am not sure if Sender is a model and if it has any association between user and sender  or sender is user.

Comment: Returns "Name error in Mailbox#inbox" undefined local variable or method `message'.

Comment: I thought you changed it in messages partial. Can you try it there instead?

Comment: My mistake.  Returns "Name error in Conversation#show" undefined method `user'.

Comment: Does sender has any association with user model? As you had sender.name I want to know if it is actually user model with name attribute. If  yes then we can directly have **message.sender.profile.avatar.url**.

Comment: sender does not have any association with the user model.  How do I do that?

Comment: Can you also post the sender model?

Comment: There is no sender model, so I suppose that is the main issue then.

Comment: Then i guess sender is user. What do see when you do this `message.sender.inspect` and `message.sender.class.name`?

Comment: message.sender.inspect shows the users details (user_ID, email, time user was created, time when user last updated)  message.sender.class.name shows the name of the user:  "Chris" > User

Comment: Then this should work: `message.sender.profile.avatar.url`.

Comment: Yes, it works!  I had `message.sender.profile.avatar.url` in the conversation partial from earlier, and had forgotten to change it back to its original link.  putting your answer only in the message partial work perfect.  Sorry for my beginner ineptitude, and thank you for your patience, and answer!

Comment: I am happy to help. So now we know how to get the images, so let's make it work in conversation partial. Can you tell from which page you are calling that partial. How are message and conversation called? Are messages part of the conversation? I think in the conversation partial you want to show the image of the user who started the conversation where as in the messages partial showing the image of the sender of each message.

Comment: In the conversation partial, the original link that I had: conversation.originator.profile.avatar.url is working just as I would like it to, which is to show the original creator of the conversation.  when click 'view message', we are taken into the message, which is where my original problem had come up with the avatars only displaying the originator.  You've completely  solved my issue!  please post your solution below so I can select it as correct.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was showing the conversation originator's image in the messages partial by using this method `conversation.originator.profile.avatar.url`.

So the fix is to use the association between *messages, user and profile* to get the image of the sender.

```
message.sender.profile.avatar.url
```